# Getopt::Long multiple switches

Tags: perl, getopt

I have three methods and two switches

I would like

- MethodA to be run if SwitchA is set
- MethodB to be run if SwitchA and SwitchB is set
- MethodC to be run if SwitchA and SwitchB is set and an arguement for SwitchB is produced

Like so

```
./main --switchA
./main --switchA --switchB
./main --switchA --switchB Hello
```

My code

```
my $result = GetOptions{
             "SwitchA" => \$opt_a,
             "SwitchB:s" => \$opt_b
   };
            

 methodA if($opt_a);
 methodB if($opt_a && $opt_b eq "");
 methodC if($opt_a && $opt_b ne "")
```

I have tried different things but essentially, If I just want MethodB to run, Method A always runs, and if I want MethodB to run, MethodA always runs.

Haven't got round to testing MethodC yet.

Comment: This isnt the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
methodA if $opt_a && !defined($opt_b);
methodB if $opt_a && defined($opt_b) && $opt_b eq "";
methodC if $opt_a && defined($opt_b) && $opt_b ne "";
```

or

```
if ($opt_a) {
   if (defined($opt_b)) {
      if ($opt_b eq "") {
         methodB
      } else {
         methodC
      }
   } else {
      methodA
   }
}
```